# I need to format my output without ruining my encryption algorithm

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography

Im doing a railroad cipher (zigzag cipher) however you may call it, I finally seemed to get my code to work properly and I got it to print the correct output, but unfortunately my teacher calls for the output to be printed 80 columns wide (80 characters per line). Unfortunately, the way my encryption is set up I can not find a way to do this since I set my encryption "rail by rail".

For the assignment we must read in the file, and strip it of all spaces and special characters, and to make all uppercase letters lower-case. Then encrypt the message. My issue is the printing portion in the encrypt function.

since its ran from command line here are the files i used

the first file pointer is for the rails, sample would be: 9
second file pointer is the text, sample i used is:

We shall not flag or fail. We shall go on to the end. We shall fight in France, we 
shall fight on the seas and oceans, we shall fight with growing confidence and 
growing strength in the air, we shall defend our island, whatever the cost may be, we 
shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, we shall fight in 
the fields and in the streets, we shall fight in the hills. we shall never surrender!

my output is correct according to my teachers output, but unfortunately i get 30% off for not having it 80 characters per line... this is due in a few hours but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
I would show the output for reference but I don't know how to copy and paste from the command line, and it only runs from there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

# define MAX 10000

void condense(char* str)
{
    int original=0;
    int newplace =0;

    while (str[original] != '\0')
    {
        if(isalpha(str[original] ))
        {
            str[newplace]= tolower(str[original]);
            ++newplace;
        }
        ++original;
    }
    str[newplace] = '\0';
}


char * deblank(char *str)
{
  char *out = str, *put = str;

  for(; *str != '\0'; ++str)
  {
    if(*str != ' ')
      *put++ = *str;
  }
  *put = '\0';

  return out;
}

void encrypt(int rail,char *plain)
{
    char railfence[rail][MAX],buf[2];
    int i;
    int number=0,increment=1;


    buf[1]='\0';
    for(i=0;i<rail;i++)
        railfence[i][0]='\0';

    for(i=0;i<strlen(plain);i++)
{
    if(number+increment==rail)
        increment=-1;
    else if(number+increment==-1)
        increment=1;

    buf[0]=plain[i];
    strcat(railfence[number],buf);
    number+=increment;
}
    for(i=0;i<rail;i++)
    printf("%s",railfence[i]);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


int rail,mode;
char text[MAX];

FILE* fp1;
FILE* fp2;

fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

int key;
fscanf(fp1, "%d", &key);
printf("key is %d", key);

char c;
int index = 0;

    fgets(text, 10000, fp2);
    printf("%s \n", text);

  // text[index] = '0';

    char nospace[MAX];
    deblank(text);

    printf("text deblanked: %s \n", text);
    //printf("%s", deblank(text));
    condense(text);

    printf("\nthe text condensed is: %s", text);

    printf("\n the text encrypted is \n");
    encrypt(key,text);




return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Instead of printing each rail as a whole, print each rail character by character, and count. In the example below I assume your instructor's *80 characters per line* is 79 characters of ciphertext plus one newline character. I do not know whether you are expected to print a newline at the end of the ciphertext, but if so just add `printf("\n");` at the end of encrypt (though you might want to check that there was at least one character of ciphertext before doing so).

```
void encrypt(int rail,char *plain)
{
    char railfence[rail][MAX],buf[2];
    int i, col = 0, j, len; // added col, j, and len
    int number=0,increment=1;


    buf[1]='\0';
    for(i=0;i<rail;i++)
        railfence[i][0]='\0';

    for(i=0;i<strlen(plain);i++)
{
    if(number+increment==rail)
        increment=-1;
    else if(number+increment==-1)
        increment=1;

    buf[0]=plain[i];
    strcat(railfence[number],buf);
    number+=increment;
}
    for(i=0;i<rail;i++)
    {
        len = strlen(railfence[i]); // get the length of the rail
        for(j=0;j<len;++j) // for each char in the rail
        {
            printf("%c", railfence[i][j]);
            if (++col==79) {
                col = 0;
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other than that, I thoroughly recommend using more whitespace in your formatting, as well as checking things like whether the user passes in two arguments or not, whether your files were opened successfully or not, and also remembering to close any files you open.

As result, your program is hard to read, and currently behaves badly if I do not provide both command line arguments or if I give it non-existent files.

Comment: Looks good + 1.  May need a final `if (col != 0) printf("\n");` after the loop.

Comment: Unless I missed it, OP's code doesn't print one so neither do I. Added a note about that though.

Comment: This most certainly worked, thanks! except your assumption was off, i actually need 80 characters, then the new line. Do i just change 79 to 80? @IskarJarak

Comment: That's why I stated my assumption. Yes, just change 79 to 80.

Comment: hey, so i had a chance to mess with it to make it 80 words per line, I changed the value 79 to 80 in the if(++col==79) part, but now i have an extra line in between each sentence, any way to avoid this? it reverts to normal if I put it back to 79 @IskarJarak

Comment: That is probably just your terminal/console wrapping the line, not an actual extra newline being printed (and that is also why I assumed 80 chars meant 79+newline).

Comment: okay, thank you very much for all your help friend! unfortunately I can't vote you up since I am new here.

Comment: No problem. Don't worry about it, I get rep from you accepting the question, and I don't really answer things on SO for the rep anyway ;)

Comment: P.S. if you are on a system where you can change the terminal width (i.e. not Windows), try making it wider to see if the line wrap disappears.